# Identity of the pushforward of a vector field using a Jacobi bracket.

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives, vectors, differential-forms

Let $Z(u,v)$ be the vector field $Z(u,v)=(u^2+u,v^2+v)$, let $\Gamma_t$ denote its flow. I have shown that $[X,Z]=Z-X$.

Show that $(\Gamma_t)_*X=e^{-t}X-(e^{-t}-1)Z$.

Could someone please show me how to do this please.

Comment: You defined $F$ but then it somehow disappeared from the question. If you set $Y=X-Z$ you get from your calculation $[Y,Z]=-Y$, and you need to show $(\Gamma_t)_*Y=e^{-t}Y$.

Comment: @user8268 Could you fully explain how you could solve this

Comment: $F$ was a mistake.

Comment: If $Y=X-Z$ we have $[Y,Z]=-Y$ and need to show that it implies $(\Gamma_t)_*Y=e^{-t}Y$.

 You have two options: I guess you saw a proof of the fact that it $W$ is a vector field such that $[W,Z]=0$ then $(\Gamma_t)_*W=W$; review that proof and see what happens in the case $[Y,Z]=-Y$. 

Another possibility (that you might like more :) is to define vector fields on $\mathbb R^3$ (coordinates $t,u,v$)
$\tilde Z=(1,u^2+u, v^2+v)$, $\tilde Y=(0,e^t Y_1,e^t Y_2)$ (where $Y=(Y_1,Y_2)$) and check that $[\tilde Z,\tilde Y]=0$.

I'll let you check the signs and finish the proof, as it looks homeworkish.

Comment: @user8268 Apologies. I meant Jacobi bracket. This isnt a homework question its from a past exam paper, dont worry this question wont exactly count for credit.